# SIGSEGV! error when trying to interact with Google Cloud Storage bucket w python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am writing a Google cloud function. Part of it's responsibility is to write files to a Cloud storage bucket. I believe I have bucket permissions set up and my service account, etc, but any time I try to interact with the bucket (upload files, or even bucket.exists()) I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Worker (pid:12345) was sent SIGSEGV!

This seems like a memory error, however the file contents is small (37k), and like I said it even happens when I just call bucket.exists(). The bucket does exists, and the filepath is correct, and the file is good, as I can write it to disk and access it just fine. My hunch is it's still some issue with GCP auth/roles, etc. but I can't find the issue and the error doesn't help much. Any thoughts?

```
def upload_blob_from_memory(bucket_name, contents, destination_blob_name):
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('/my-service-account-creds.json')
    storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials,project='my-bucket')
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    # fails here at bucket.exists(), but same issue any time I want to interact with a bucket
    print(f"bucket.exists() {bucket.exists()}")
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_string(contents)

    print(
        f"{destination_blob_name} with contents {contents} uploaded to {bucket_name}."
    )
```

NOTE: this function is not deployed, I'm testing locally with:

```
functions-framework-python --target my-function
```

Comment: Add logging to verify the credentials are correct.

Comment: Credentials are correct. I never ended up solving this, and just did the function development in the cloud functions interface in GCP, which was much slower than being able to dev/test locally would have been.